# Tool to widen font

Tags: fonts

For my programming I am looking for a wide font, that is easy to read. The goal is to have a font that trades many columns for many lines - sort of the opposite of Condensed and Narrow.

The best I have found so far is Droid Sans Mono, but I would like to have it even wider.

Is there a tool (or maybe just a config?) that can squeeze that font to, say, 70% of the height while keeping the width in a format that is understood by Konsole?

**Result**

https://oletange.wordpress.com/2015/08/14/flat-font-for-your-terminal/

Comment: My first impression with "tool to squeeze font" was that you wanted a narrower font. Perhaps a better title is "tool to widen font".

Comment: DejaVu Sans Mono is fairly wide. Not sure there is such a font widener tool though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can widen the font with the FontForge. Select all glyphs, choose Element-Transformations-Transform-Scale, set scale percents on X and save as a new font.
But better to find a font that is already wide. You should try Source Code Pro, Input, or Anonymous Pro.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @contemplator I have now stretched DroidMonoSans using FontForge.

https://oletange.wordpress.com/2015/08/14/flat-font-for-your-terminal/